# CSS images not working with Opera Next Extension

Tags: opera-extension

I'm in the process of porting a Chrome extension to Opera Next. Everything seems to be working except for CSS images.

In Chrome, we're specifying an image in CSS like this:

```
#webapps-compose img {
  content: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/skin/webapps/compose-128.png");
}
```

Will this work on Opera Next when it is released?

Comment: FYI Opera Next has already been released, 15.0.1147.100, get it at http://www.opera.com/developer/next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to specify `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__` in your stylesheet, even if you're embedding the style sheet on a non-extension page.

`url()`s within a stylesheet are *always* resolved relative to the path of the style sheet itself. So, it suffices to use the following style sheet, the image will correctly be displayed.

```css
/* .css file within your extension directory */
#webapps-compose img {
    content: url("/skin/webapps/compose-128.png");
}
```